# Find customers that have bought something during a period as well as before and not before

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables:

1. `orders` with `orderid | orderdate | userid | ...` and
2. `users` with `userid | ...`

where I join them both:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
JOIN users ON orders.userid = users.id
```

to get a table with all orders committed by users.

Now I need to get all customers that have bought something between 2016-11-01
and 2017-31-01:

1. at least once before 2016-11-01 and also between 2016-11-01 and 2017-02-01 and
2. nothing before 2016-11-01 but have bought something for the first time between
   2016-11-01 and 2017-02-01.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What's your problem? Why the downvotes?

Comment: Post sample data and desired output.

Comment: Ok, sorry. @Baro solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*They probably gave you negative votes because you did not include a test, a query you tried. And it looks like you're totally delegating the job.*

Anyway, this is an untested query, and dates are often problematic in relation to the region. Consider it as the idea of how you can do (Probably there will be cleaner methods):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders 
        WHERE orderdate >= CONVERT(datetime, '2016-11-01' , 101) 
        AND orderdate <= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-31-01' , 101)
        AND userid = users.id)
    AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders 
        WHERE orderdate <= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-31-01' , 101)
        AND userid = users.id)
```

Comment: @DStanley Absolutely agree with you ! Edited :)

Comment: I am really really sorry. I actually solved it myself with `INTERSECT` for the first query and `EXCEPT` for the second query. I am really sorry for using your time. But thanks anyway. I try your query as well!!! Thank

Comment: @implicit_knowledge Do not excuse me. I'm glad you solved and even more if you did it alone :)